# How do I add text to every other item in a python list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like:

```
mylist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

I want to add some text to every other item so it looks like this:

```
mylist = ["1a", "2", "3a", "4", "5a"]
```

I wrote this, which works fine for *every* item.  How do I make it apply only to *every other* item?

```
mylist2 = ["a" + item for item in mylist]
```

Comment: Should the "a" be before the number of after it? Your list comprehension does not match what you want.

Comment: I would actually like to know how to put it on either side, but once I have one solution, I can try changing the order to move it.

Comment: What is the difference between *"every item"* and *"every other item"*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do it would be this:

```
mylist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
res = [x + ('a' if i%2 == 0 else '') for i, x in enumerate(mylist)]
```

which results in:

```
['1a', '2', '3a', '4', '5a']
```

---

This approach takes advantage of the fact that the index of the terms you want to change when divided by 2 have a remainder of 1. See [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: congrats for the answer. What I don't like about it is the fact that you're adding an empty string, instead of using the ternary on the whole expression. adding to an empty string can be avoided here

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Likewise. I also though about this but somehow reached the conclusion that it is equally fast\efficient. If this is not the case, I would be very curious and grateful to know why.

Comment: because `x + ''` will generate another string, instead of just using `x`. that's probably not noticeable on small lists.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Interestingly enough though, `x+'' is x` returns `True`.

Comment: that's because of string interning. I think there's an optimization in the case you add to `""`.

Comment: So it seems it gets optimized-out right? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: nope, you're right. Adding empty string returns the same string as before.

Comment: It may return the same string, but it's still another operation in the interpreter, so slower than `(x +'a' if i%2 == 0 else x)`.

Answer (score 10):

Try This:

```
for i in range(0, len(mylist), 2):
    mylist[i] = mylist[i] + "a"
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
for i in range(0, len(mylist), 2):
    mylist[i] += "a"
```

Answer (score 6):

use `enumerate` and a modulo to test odd or even values with a ternary.

```
mylist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
mylist2 = [item if i%2 else "a" + item for i,item in enumerate(mylist)]
```

result:

```
>>> mylist2
['a1', '2', 'a3', '4', 'a5']
```

to get `1a`, etc... just switch `"a" + item` by `item + "a"`

Comment: The thing is that the list doesn't necessarily starts with an odd number... I'd rather use `mylist2 = [item if not int(item)%2 else "a" + item for item in mylist]`

Comment: @TonyPellerin it's not about the values of the list, but the index of the elements. OP example is misleading. the list could be `['a','b','c']`

Answer (score 4):

A bit weird solution, which makes use of iterators:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> mylist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
>>> suffix = cycle(["a", ""])
>>> [l + s for l, s in zip(mylist, suffix)]
['1a', '2', '3a', '4', '5a']
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by Netwave in comments, here is the very-super-pythonic solution!

```
>>> import itertools, operator
>>> list(map(operator.add, mylist, itertools.cycle(("a", ""))))
['1a', '2', '3a', '4', '5a']
```

Comment: we like wierd here.

Comment: One more twist: `map(operator.add, mylist, cycle(("a", "")))`

Comment: @Netwave: SUPER-PYTHONIC solution!

Answer (score 0):

`mylist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
text_list = [str(x) + 'a' if i % 2 == 0 else x for i, x in enumerate(mylist)]`